# Drools won't working

Tags: java, drools

I have some problem with Drools.
In my rule.drl file i have this rule,checking if Article exists in working memory

```
rule "rule-2"
    //include attributes such as "salience" here...
    agenda-group "article-numbers"
    when
        //condition
        exists (Article())
    then
        System.out.println("bbbbb");
        //actions

end
```

and in Java class i have method

```
public void orderArticles(Article a){
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("sesija");
        kieSession.insert(a);
        kieSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("article-numbers").setFocus();
        kieSession.fireAllRules();

        ar.updateBrojArtikala(a);
        ar.updateDodatiArtikle(a);
        System.out.println(a);

        kieSession.dispose();
    }
```

where i am accessing Drools,and inserting Article in working memory.But even with this simple rule,I get the following error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -15
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.DialectUtil.parseModifiedProperties(DialectUtil.java:707) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.DialectUtil.rewriteModifyDescr(DialectUtil.java:640) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.DialectUtil.rewriteDescr(DialectUtil.java:581) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.DialectUtil.fixBlockDescr(DialectUtil.java:162) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.DialectUtil.fixBlockDescr(DialectUtil.java:120) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.asm.AbstractASMConsequenceBuilder.consequenceContext(AbstractASMConsequenceBuilder.java:57) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.asm.AbstractASMConsequenceBuilder.build(AbstractASMConsequenceBuilder.java:33) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuilder.build(RuleBuilder.java:116) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.addRule(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1820) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1111) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileAllRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:989) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildRules(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:264) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:122) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:105) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:244) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.createKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:561) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:524) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:687) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:655) ~[drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at rs.ac.uns.ftn.informatika.rest.service.ArticlesDroolsService.orderArticles(ArticlesDroolsService.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at rs.ac.uns.ftn.informatika.rest.controller.SalesmanController.orderArticle(SalesmanController.java:65) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

meaning that I'm accessing index -15 of string,which I don't do at all(!)
When I'm debugging,it always stops at

> KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("sesija");

and there breaks.
I think this is very strange,it seems like something is wrong with my settings or kieContainer..?Does anyone experienced something similar?I think that my settings are fine,but I don't know what could be a problem..Does someone have some suggestion how to solve this?Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Is that your entire DRL?

Comment: Yes,it is.why are you asking?am i doing this right? i thought this should work..

Comment: Why did i get -2 reputation?

Comment: Look at where it's failing: when drools is trying to parse the dialect. What dialect are you using? Did you try to declare the dialect in your drl? eg: `dialect "mvel"` ?

Comment: no I didn't..I didn't use any dialect..i have some examples that are working in which there isn't any dialect..should I use dialect?in my import section is only `import rs.ac.uns.ftn.informatika.rest.model.*;
import rs.ac.uns.ftn.informatika.rest.repository.*; ` where are my models and repositories..

Comment: i added dialect "mvel" and dialect "java" and it still the same..my code always throws error in line `KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("sesija");`

Comment: anyone know this??

Comment: I think the dialect has nothing to do with your error. Are you importing the class `Article` in your DRL? Are you defining a `package` in your DRL? Could you please add the definition of the `Article` class and your full DRL?

Comment: this my full drl: 
`package rules 
import rs.ac.uns.ftn.informatika.rest.model.*; 
rule "rule-2" //include attributes such as "salience" here... 
agenda-group "article-numbers" 
when 
//condition 
exists (User()) 
$k:User() 
then 
System.out.println("user postoji!"); 
System.out.println($k.getUsername()); 
//actions 
end` ,
and I changed model from Article to User..User has fields String username,String password,String role.

Comment: I defined package,that is `package rules`,and I imported all my models,and so Article/User with `rs.ac.uns.ftn.informatika.rest.model.*;`

Comment: Which Drools' version are you using? I did a similar test in 7.0.0 and it works fine. Could you reproduce this error in a simple project that you can share with us?

Comment: I am using 6.5.0..error is the same,it is always in line KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("sesija"); ,i think there is the problem..

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Drools 6.5. Unless you provide a self-contained project showing this error I won't be able to help you.

Comment: my project consists of spring-boot,mysql and drools,and in this link i have mysql script besides project,which should be executed,it isn't just drools java project...it is on this link [link](https://ufile.io/w4u9i)..anyway,thank you for helping,i would buy you a beer if you're around!:D

Comment: @slomilll were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When I asked if that was your entire DRL, you were not supposed to lie :P**

The application you posted in your comments includes 2 .drl files full of rules. One of this rules - `update price for whole bill-1`- contains a typo in its Right Hand Side. For some reason, Drools was choking when processing this line and generating an impossible to understand error.

The line I'm talking about is the following one:

`modify($bill){setFinalPrice((int)(0.95*$bill.getFinalPrice())};`

If you pay attention, there are 5 opening brackets `(` but only 4 closing brackets `)`.
When adding the missing bracket, everything seems to work (or at least the rules compile OK):

`modify($bill){setFinalPrice((int)(0.95*$bill.getFinalPrice()))};`

Hope it helps,